# Add content in wp login page

Tags: wp-login-form

I have customized my wp login page according with my custom theme.
I would like to add a content box inside my wp login page who invite the user to go through my custom registration page if he haven't account on the website.
I searched  lot but any option for me, and I would like not use plug in in priority. 
Thanks in advance if you know how to add content in wp login page.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

Check out the "Make a Custom Login Page" section.

```
wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
```

Replace this bit with a link to your custom registration page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with this code :

```
function custom_login_message( $message ) {
if ( empty($message) ){
    return "<p>content</p>";
} else {
    return $message;
}
```

}

add_filter( 'login_message', 'custom_login_message' );